# Error when caching flutter engine with custom dart entrypoint

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-android

I'm trying to cache and reuse a FlutterEngine with a custom entry point (method different than main in main.dart). It's working well on debug mode but on profile or release I got an error when I'm creating the flutter engine. I don't know what else I could do since it's working on debug mode and it seems that everything is correct.

This is the error that I'm getting

```
E/flutter (25371): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(94)] Dart Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: No top-level getter 'mainLockScreen' declared.
E/flutter (25371): Receiver: top-level
E/flutter (25371): Tried calling: mainLockScreen, stack trace: #0      NoSuchMethodError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:218)
E/flutter (25371):
E/flutter (25371): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(718)] Could not resolve main entrypoint function.
E/flutter (25371): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(202)] Could not run the run main Dart entrypoint.
E/flutter (25371): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(384)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter (25371): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(574)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

I already use @pragma in my custom entry point like that:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void mainLockScreen() {
  debugPrint("mainLock");
  .... custom code that runs runApp
}
```

And I'm caching the engine in MyApplication class (I defined it in AndroidManifest, the class looks like that):

```
package productivity.timetracker.mytime

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.WindowManager
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineCache

class LockScreenActivity : FlutterActivity() {


    override fun provideFlutterEngine(context: Context): FlutterEngine? =
        FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get("LockScreenEngine")


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true)
        } else {
            window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            )
        }
    }

    override fun getDartEntrypointFunctionName(): String = "mainLockScreen"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems as though multiple entrypoints are kinda broken right now in flutter version 2.8.1 ...
Here is a github issue talking about it.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91841

I'm facing the same issue right now. In the thread people say that if you are using cached flutter engine this might help.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91841#issuecomment-1006026551